# bootstrap collapse collapses when clicking on calendar icon

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a bootstrap panel-collapse as follows

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                            Business/Financial Information <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#BusFinInfo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span></a>
                        </div>
<div id="BusFinInfo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

and an ajax calendar extender as follows

```
<div class="input-group">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID='txtTermNotifctnDate' runat='server' CssClass='form-control'></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="inputCalenderTermNotifctnDate">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnTermNotifctnDate" runat="server"><i class="icon-Calendar"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </span>
                                                <ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceTermNotifctnDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTermNotifctnDate"
                                                    PopupButtonID="lnkBtnExecutionDate" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"></ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                            </div>
```

The problem is that when I click on the calendar control, the panel collapses.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake that I overlooked. PopupButtonID was wrong and didn't match the link button.